# Losing upperback tightness at top of concentric of bench-press

Tags: bench-press

When I push the bar to the very top when doing the bench press, it seems so all tightness I had in my shoulders go away. Am I doing something wrong or am I supposed to intentionally limit the concentric?

Comment: Your question is confusing and I'm unsure what you are actually asking. Are you aware eccentric is the negative part of a rep, meaning the lowering of the barbel.

Comment: Mix up of words @Ethan

Comment: Please edit you question to make it more clear or add details to further outline what you're asking.